# Query to retrieve records containing Unix dates

Tags: mysql

One column in a table in my MySQL database stores date in Unix format.

I am trying to retrieve all rows where the date is later than a specific date. How do I write a query to do this? I want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date > "yyyy-mm-dd";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) > "yyyy-mm-dd";
```

Comment: I believe Unix dates are stored as seconds from 1/1/1970 00:00 as an integer. The formula above converts the date into something more readable. but you can also use the integer value of the datetime you want.